# Reference an item in the second layer of a nested enumeration

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I have a nested enumeration in my Appendix that looks a little like this:

> 1. Something
> 2. Interview
>
> 2.1 First Interview
>
> 2.2 Second Interview

I use the following code in the Appendix:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Firstelement
\label{app:1}
\item Interviews
\label{app:interviews}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item  first interview \label{app:int1}
    \item  second interview \label{app:int2}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Now, whenever I reference one of the nested items in the text I get **item 22.1** instead of **item 2.1.** like I would want to.

I use `\ref{app:int2}` when referencing in the Text.

How can I achieve this?

*Note* I am using a template provided by my school, which uses the following code to achieve the nested list:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
```